# What is the better/correct way of using Promise.all with React-Redux-Thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```
export const FETCH_DB_BEGIN = 'FETCH_DB_BEGIN'
export const FETCH_DB_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DB_SUCCESS'
export const FETCH_DB_FAILURE = 'FETCH_DB_FAILURE'

export const fetchDatabase = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const profile_url = 'localhost:5000/profiles'
        const release_url = 'localhost:5000/releases'
        const emp_url = 'localhost:5000/users'
        let promises = []

        let options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: null,
        }
        dispatch(fetchDbBegin());

        // run the script async. change state when it's done.
        let profile_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(profile_url, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(resText => {
                    // Use Dispatch Here?
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        promises.push(profile_promise)

        // run the script async. change state when it's done.
        let release_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(release_url, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(resText => {
                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        promises.push(release_promise)

        // run the script async. change state when it's done.
        let emp_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(emp_url, options)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(resText => {

                })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        promises.push(emp_promise)

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
            console.log(values)
        })
    }
}

export const fetchDbBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_BEGIN
});

export const fetchDbSuccess = (data) => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_SUCCESS,
    payload: { data }
});

export const fetchDbFailure = (err) => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_FAILURE,
    payload: { err }
});
```

I am in a process of refactoring a React class component to use `Redux`. It initially had all API calls inside the `componentDidMount` and it was so messy.

I am using `redux-thunk` to move this out from the class component.

The `fetchDatabase` in my `databaseAction.js` does everything that `componentDidMount` did in the class component.

Normally if it was a single API call, I would have just dispatched the `fetchDbSuccess` as the API call was done successfully. However, using `Promise.All` which takes three async API calls, I am not sure whether I should

1. create a separate action for each API call (`fetchProfileSuccess`, `fetchReleaseSuccess`, and `fetchUserSuccess`) and dispatch each one of them at the end of each Promise (the place where I put `//Use Dispatch Here?` in the code.

OR

2. Just dispatch single `fetchDbSuccess` when the `Promise.all` gets resolved.

If I choose to do 2, am I supposed to update all three `states` in my reducer?

Thanks

Comment: How many actions you dispatch depends on which state updates you expect to take place. If your UI doesn't care about all three fetches, only if the top-level fetch finished, you could just do the one success action. If you're wanting to show something specific for each one, you'd do the separate actions.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks. So are both approaches correct?

Comment: Yep. By the way, your sample code isn't doing the Promises correctly since the `new Promise` callbacks aren't calling `resolve` or `reject` (and the `new Promise` wrappers aren't necessary since `fetch()` already returns Promises)

Comment: @Jacob How should I fix them? Initially I had `this.setState` after `.then(resText => ...` in the Class Component so that it updates each data once the fetch was successfully done and it seemed to do what I intended.

Comment: I will post in an answer so there's more space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should only dispatch and update state if you have code that *cares* about said state updates. For example, if you're just wanting to show a single spinner then have the spinner go away when fully completed, your user doesn't necessarily care about each atomic operation, so you don't need it reflected in state. If you have a UI that does show each, then you would want those extra dispatches.

By the way, your Promises look a bit overcomplicated. If you decide you don't need those extra state changes, you can simplify to this:

```js
export const FETCH_DB_BEGIN = 'FETCH_DB_BEGIN'
export const FETCH_DB_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_DB_SUCCESS'
export const FETCH_DB_FAILURE = 'FETCH_DB_FAILURE'

export const fetchDatabase = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchDbBegin());

        const urls = [
            'http://localhost:5000/profiles',
            'http://localhost:5000/releases',
            'http://localhost:5000/users'
        ];

        const options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: null,
        }

        const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());

        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
            .then(([profile, release, employee]) => {
                dispatch(fetchDbSuccess({ profile, release, employee }));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(fetchDbFailure(err));
            });
    }
}

export const fetchDbBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_BEGIN
});

export const fetchDbSuccess = (data) => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_SUCCESS,
    payload: { data }
});

export const fetchDbFailure = (err) => ({
    type: FETCH_DB_FAILURE,
    payload: { err }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jacob, this is beautiful. One thing that I want to clarify is that how many times does `fetchDbSuccess` in the `Promise.all` get called? Is it just once since it is called after all three `fetchJson`s are resolved?

Comment: It's only called once. `Promise.all` returns a regular Promise. Once all child promises in the array succeed, it resolves as a success with an array of each result. If any of the child promises fail, it rejects with the first error.